# Traefik v2 as a reverse proxy without docker

Tags: reverse-proxy, traefik

I have read the documentation but I can not figure out how to configure Traefik v2 to replace Nginx as a reverse proxy for web sites (virtual hosts) without involving Docker. Ideally there would be let'sencrypt https as well.

I have a service running at http://127.0.0.1:4000 which I would like to reverse proxy to from http://myhost.com:80

This is the configuration i've come up with so far:

```html
[Global]
checkNewVersion = true

[log]
  level = "DEBUG"
  filePath = "log-file.log"

[accessLog]
  filePath =  "log-access.log"
  bufferingSize =  100

[entrypoints]
    [entrypoints.http]
    address = ":80"

[http]
    [http.routers]
       [http.routers.my-router]
          rule = "Host(`www.myhost.com`)"
          service = "http"
          entrypoint=["http"]

    [http.services]
          [http.services.http.loadbalancer]
            [[http.services.http.loadbalancer.servers]]
              url = "http://127.0.0.1:4000"
```

Comment: I resolved the dashboard 404 and wrote and complete the tutorial on deployment without docker.
Checkout: https://adapttive.com/blog/deploying-node-js-app-with-pm-2-and-traefik

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured it out, 
the first part to note is that in traefik v2 there are two types of configuration, static and dynamic. So I created two files, traefik.toml and traefik-dynamic.toml.

contents of traefik.toml:

```html
[log]
  level = "DEBUG"
  filePath = "log-file.log"

[accessLog]
  filePath =  "log-access.log"
  bufferingSize =  100

[providers]
  [providers.file]
    filename = "traefik-dynamic.toml"

[api]
  dashboard = true
  debug = true

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.web-secure]
    address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.dashboard]
    address = ":8080"

[certificatesResolvers.sample.acme]
  email = "myemail@example.com"
  storage = "acme.json"

  [certificatesResolvers.sample.acme.httpChallenge]
    # used during the challenge
    entryPoint = "web"
```

traefik-dynamic.toml:

```html
[http]
    # Redirect to https
    [http.middlewares]
      [http.middlewares.test-redirectscheme.redirectScheme]
        scheme = "https"

    [http.routers]
       [http.routers.my-router]
          rule = "Host(`www.example.com`)"
          service = "phx"
          entryPoints = ["web-secure"]
       [http.routers.my-router.tls]
          certResolver = "sample"

    [http.services]
          [http.services.phx.loadbalancer]
            [[http.services.phx.loadbalancer.servers]]
              url = "http://127.0.0.1:4000"
```

Comment: load balancer is working fine but when i tried to enter dashboard it's giving 404 page not found error. do you have any idea?

Comment: I resolved the dashboard 404 and wrote and complete the tutorial on deployment without docker.
Checkout: https://adapttive.com/blog/deploying-node-js-app-with-pm-2-and-traefik

Comment:  +1 liked detailed the blog!

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks for this! Regarding dashboard: `api:
  insecure: true
  dashboard: true` has to be activated as well. Also see here: https://github.com/DoTheEvo/Traefik-v2-examples

Answer (score 3):

You can also use Traefik v2 to reverse proxy to a service running on the localhost without using Nginx as explained here using *File* (and not *Docker* provider) for Traefik.

First, route calls to `myhost.com` through `localhost` by updating `/etc/hosts` like:

```
127.0.0.1 myhost.com
```

Create a minimal `docker-compose.yml` like:

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  proxy:
    image: traefik:2.0
    command:
      - "--providers.file.filename=/etc/traefik/proxy-config.toml"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./proxy-config.toml:/etc/traefik/proxy-config.toml:ro
```

This Compose file creates a read-only volume containing the dynamic configuration for the Traefik reverse proxy standing in for Nginx as requested. It uses the *File* provider for Traefik and not *Docker* and a blank HTTP address mapped to port `80` for the entrypoint. This is a complete Compose file in itself. Beyond that all that's needed is the reverse proxy configuration for Traefik.

Configure the Traefik reverse proxy `proxy-config.toml` in the same directory:

```
[http.routers.test-streamrouter]
  rule = "Host(`myhost.com`)"
  service = "test-loadbalancer"
  entryPoints = ["web"]

[[http.services.test-loadbalancer.loadBalancer.servers]]
  url = "http://host.docker.internal:4000"
```

This is a sample reverse proxy in its entirety. It can be enhanced with middlewares to perform URL rewriting, update domain names or even redirect users if that's your aim. A single load balancer is used as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58496677/712334). And `host.docker.internal` is used to return the host's [internal networking address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58496677/712334).

**Note:** At time of writing `"host.docker.internal"` only works with Docker for Mac and will fail on Linux. However, you may be able to use the Compose service name instead (i.e. `"proxy"`).

Once you get this working you can set up the Let's Encrypt stuff or swap between development and production configurations using the [`TRAEFIK_PROVIDERS_FILE_FILENAME`](https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/reference/static-configuration/env/) environment variable.

Comment: I tried it but I'm getting `502 Bad Gateway' caused by: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8001: connect: connection refused"` error.
My scenario is I'm sending `curl http://example.com:5050/storeData` and I'm running  a `go application server ` on port `:8001` and this port is not exposed. so I'm trying to use `traefik` which listens for `example.com:5050` and then forward it to my `go application server` listening on port `8001`.

Comment: my proxy.toml file


```
[http.routers]
  [http.routers.myrouter]
    rule = "Host(`example.com`) && Path(`/storeData`))"
    service = "goserver"
    entryPoints = ["web"]

  [http.routers.myrouter1]
    rule = "Host(`example.com`) && Path(`/getData`))"
    service = "goserver"
    entryPoints = ["web"]

[http.services]
  [http.services.goserver.loadBalancer]
    [[http.services.goserver.loadBalancer.servers]]
      url = "http://localhost:8001"
```

Comment: I'm able to fix it. In `proxy-config.toml` file I changed the `url` to `http://instance_priv_IP:8001`

Answer (score -3):

You can

1. use container names within the same bridged network instead of localhost
2. link middlewares and services without @file suffix

Please mind, that in the yaml and toml file, you need to pay attention to lower-uppercase of the properties. Whereas in docker it is `loadbalancer`, you need to write `loadBalencer` in the config file.

```yaml
http:
  middlewares:
    docs:
      stripPrefix:
        prefixes:
          - "/docs"
    restapi:
      stripPrefix:
        prefixes:
          - "/api/v1"
  routers:
    restapi:
      rule: "PathPrefix(`/api/v1`)"
      middlewares:
        - "restapi"
      service: "restapi"
      entryPoints:
        - http
    docs:
      rule: "PathPrefix(`/docs`)"
      middlewares:
        - "docs"
      service: "docs"
      entryPoints:
        - http
    client:
      rule: "PathPrefix(`/`)"
      service: "client"
      entryPoints:
        - http
    help:
      rule: "PathPrefix(`/server/sicon/help`)"
  services:
    restapi:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "http://sicon_backend:1881"
    docs:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "http://sicon_backend:1882"
    client:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "http://sicon_client"
```