# Traefik v2 reverse proxy without Docker

Tags: go, networking, microservices, reverse-proxy, traefik

I have a dead simple Golang microservice (no Docker, just simple binary file) which returns simple message on GET-request.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:36001/api/operability/list'
```

> {"message": "ping 123"}

Now I want to do reverse proxy via Traefik-v2, so I've made configuration file "traefik.toml":

```
[global]
  checkNewVersion = false
  sendAnonymousUsage = false

[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":8090"

    [entryPoints.traefik]
    address = ":8091"

[log]
    level = "DEBUG"
    filePath = "logs/traefik.log"
[accessLog]
    filePath = "logs/access.log"

[api]
    insecure = true
    dashboard = true

[providers]
  [providers.file]
    filename = "traefik.toml"

# dynamic conf
[http]
    [http.routers]
        [http.routers.my-router]
            rule = "Path(`/proxy`)"
            service = "my-service"
            entryPoints = ["web"]
    [http.services]
        [http.services.my-service.loadBalancer]
            [[http.services.my-service.loadBalancer.servers]]
                url = "http://localhost:36001"
```

Starting Traefik (I'm using binary distribution):

```
traefik --configFile=traefik.toml
```

Now dashboard on port 8091 works like a charm, but I struggle with reverse proxy request. I suppose it should look like this (based on my configuration file):

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:8090/proxy/api/operability/list'
```

But all I get it's just:

> 404 page not found

The question is: is there any mistake in configuration file or is it just a request typo?

**edit:**
My configuration file is based on answers in this questions:

1. [Simple reverse proxy example with Traefik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60227270/simple-reverse-proxy-example-with-traefik)
2. [Traefik v2 as a reverse proxy without docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58496270/traefik-v2-as-a-reverse-proxy-without-docker)

**edit #2:**
Traefik version info:

```
traefik version
Version:      2.4.9
Codename:     livarot
Go version:   go1.16.5
Built:        2021-06-21T16:17:58Z
OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to find the answer.

1. I'm not that smart if I've decided that Traefik would take */proxy* and simply redicrect all request to */api/**. The official docs (https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/) says that (I'm quoting):

> > Use Path if your service listens on the exact path only. For instance, Path: /products would match /products but not /products/shoes.

> > Use a *Prefix* matcher if your service listens on a particular base path but also serves requests on sub-paths. For instance, PathPrefix: /products would match /products but also /products/shoes and /products/shirts. Since the path is forwarded as-is, your service is expected to listen on /products.

2. I did not use any middleware for replacing substring of path

Now answer as example.

First at all: code for microservice in main.go file

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "{\"message\": \"ping 123\"}")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/operability/list", handler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":36001", nil))
}
```

Now, configuration file for Traefik v2 in config.tom file:

```
[global]
  checkNewVersion = false
  sendAnonymousUsage = false

[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":36000"

    [entryPoints.traefik]
    address = ":8091"

[log]
    level = "DEBUG"
    filePath = "logs/traefik.log"
[accessLog]
    filePath = "logs/access.log"

[api]
    insecure = true
    dashboard = true

[providers]
  [providers.file]
    debugLogGeneratedTemplate = true
    # Point this same file for dynamic configuration
    filename = "config.toml"
    watch = true

[http]
    [http.middlewares]
        [http.middlewares.test-replacepathregex.replacePathRegex]
            # We need middleware to replace all "/proxy/" with "/api/"
            regex = "(?:^|\\W)proxy(?:$|\\W)"
            replacement = "/api/"

    [http.routers]
        [http.routers.my-router]
            # We need to handle all request with pathes defined as "/proxy/*"
            rule = "PathPrefix(`/proxy/`)"
            service = "my-service"
            entryPoints = ["web"]
            # Use of defined middleware for path replacement
            middlewares = ["test-replacepathregex"]

    [http.services]
        [http.services.my-service.loadBalancer]
            [[http.services.my-service.loadBalancer.servers]]
                url = "http://localhost:36001/"
```

Start microservice:

```
go run main.go
```

Start traefik:

```
traefik --configFile config.toml
```

Now check if microservice works correctly:

> curl -XGET 'http://localhost:36001/api/operability/list'
>
> > {"message": "ping 123"}

And check if Traefik v2 does job well too:

> curl -XGET 'http://localhost:36000/proxy/operability/list'
>
> > {"message": "ping 123"}